# Array filtros angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filtro

tengo una aplicacion con filtros en angular que funciona correctamente, pero quisiera optimizarla, ya que tengo ifs y else por todos lados para comprobar los campos que están completos y los que no.

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input
    [(ngModel)]="c_reclutamiento"
    matInput
    placeholder="Código reclutamiento"
  />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input
    matInput
    (dateChange)="dateChange($event.value._i)"
    [matDatepicker]="picker"
    placeholder="Fecha incoporación"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

este es mi html normal con un boton de dar a BUSCAR y luego hago las comprobaciones asi...

```
    if(this.c_reclutamiento === '' && this.status_select === '' && this.fecha_incorporacion=== '' && this.market==='' && this.team===''){
  filteredData = _.filter(this.apiResponse, (item) => {
    return item
  })
}else{
  if (this.c_reclutamiento !== '' && this.status_select !== '' && this.fecha_incorporacion!== '' && this.market!=='' && this.team!=='') {
    filteredData = _.filter(this.apiResponse, (item) => {
      if (item.cod_reclutamiento.toLowerCase() == this.c_reclutamiento.toLowerCase() && item.status.toLowerCase() == this.status_select.toLowerCase() && item.fecha_incorporacion == this.fecha_incorporacion) {
        return item;
      }
    }
    )
  } else {
    if(this.status_select !== '' && this.fecha_incorporacion !== ''){
      filteredData = _.filter(this.apiResponse, (item) => {
        if (item.status.toLowerCase() == this.status_select.toLowerCase() && item.fecha_incorporacion == this.fecha_incorporacion) {
          return item;
        }
      })
    }
```

con dos filtros o tres bueno, no está optimizado pero puede pasar, el caso es que voy a tener muchos filtros y quiero que esté mucho más optimizado. No sé como poner que solo recoja los campos que tengan valor y luego coger su nombre, valor y ya hacer el filtro como le estoy haciendo. Espero vuestra ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: Para eso no podrias utilizar un validador de formulario?

Comment: Debes buscar información sobre formularios reactivos, tendrías más control sobre tu formulario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir optimizar todo debes transformar tu código a un ReactiveForm y así explotar los poderosos forms de Angular, te dejo un ejemplo para que lo apliques en tu proyecto:

El Template:

```
   <form class="proyect_two" [formGroup]="createGroupForm">

     <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Campo Uno</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="00" formControlName="campoUno">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Campo Dos</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="00" formControlName="campoDos">
   </mat-form-field>

   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Campo Tres</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="00" formControlName="campoTres">
   </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

El .TS

```
  public createGroupForm : FormGroup;
  hasChange: boolean = false;   //true cuando hay cambios detectados
  constructor(){}

  ngOninit(){
    this.makeForm()
  }

     makeForm(){
        this.createGroupForm = this._formBuilder.group({
         campoUno: new FormControl(''), //string
         campoDos: new FormControl(0), ///number
         campoTres: new FormControl('') //string
       });

      this.validateForm()
    }     



  validateForm(){

     const initialValue = this.createGroupForm.value

      this.createGroupForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {

         // cada vez que la data de cualquier control del form cambie 
         // lo veras aquí

         this.hasChange = Object.keys(initialValue).some(key => 
         this.form.value[key] != 
         initialValue[key])
      });


   }

     /**
     * Valida los controles de un formulario y retorna aquellos que hayan 
     sufrido cambios o 'estén sucios'
     * @param form Formulario a validar
     * @returns 
     */
     getDirtyValues(
      form: FormGroup | FormArray | FormControl | AbstractControl
     ): Map<string, any> | any[] | any | undefined {
        if (!form.dirty) {
          return;
        }

       if (form instanceof FormControl) {
         return form.value;
       }

       if (form instanceof FormGroup) {
          const result = new Map();
          for (const [key, control] of Object.entries(form.controls)) {
          const nestedResult = this.getDirtyValues(control);

           if (nestedResult) {
              result.set(key, this.getDirtyValues(control));
           }
       }

        return result;
     }

     if (form instanceof FormArray) {
           const result = new Array();
        form.controls.forEach(control => {
        const nestedResult = this.getDirtyValues(control);
           if (nestedResult) {
              result.push(nestedResult);
           }
        });

      return result;
    }

    throw new Error('No estas ingresando un FomControl, FormGroup o 
    FormArray');
   }
```

Aqui encuentras como crear el FormGroup y dos funciones de ayuda para conseguir validar lo que requieres:

**validateForm():** crea una suscripción en la que puedes ver los cambios de todos los campos y hacer la lógica que requieras.

**getDirtyValues():**  Evalua que controles o inputs de tu formulario han recibido edición y te los retorna, ya con esto puedes usar solamente los datos que cambiaron para tu filtro.

Espero sea de utilidad